# Determining NR within BEGIN section of awk script

Tags: bash, awk

Before awk processes the input file, I need to know how many records to expect.

In order to determine this, I have the following code in the BEGIN segment of my awk script....

```
BEGIN {

    p = ""
    j = 1

    getline             # Activates the FILENAmE variable which normally is not available in the BEGIN section of an awk script.
    n = system("wc -l " FILENAME)       # Assign the result (i.e. number of records in FILENAME) to the n variable.
    gsub(FILENAME, "|", n)      # Remove the input file name appended to the result and replace with "|" just to see what it's done!  
    print n             # See what the hell has happened.

}
```

I am hoping to see n showing the number of records, but my output looks like this....

```
12 accounts12
0
```

"accounts12" is the name of my input file....

Comment: is your input always a file or could it be a stream coming from a pipe?

Answer (score 1):

`system` returns its exit status (typically 0 if it completes successfully). So the line:

```
n = system("wc -l " FILENAME)
```

will simply result in the output of the `wc` command being printed on the screen as usual, and then `n` being set to the exit code 0.

This explains:

```
12 accounts12
0
```

The first line is the output of `wc`, the second the value of `n`.

You could try instead:

```
BEGIN {
    "wc -l " ARGV[1] | getline n;
    sub(ARGV[1], "|", n);
    print n;
}
```

This should get your `n`. It has the benefit that it won't consume the first line of your file.

Comment: Piping to "getline n" doesn't work. I get the following error...".sh: 1: 0: not found"

Comment: sorry typo. I left out a space

Answer (score 1):

you can also do this

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{n=NR; next} FNR==1{print n} ...' file{,}
```

first round it calculates the number of records, second round print the count and do the rest of the processing.

Answer (score 0):

Another way with awk :

- Set FS to \n (each line is a field)
- Set RS to \0 (only one record)
- Work on fields

  awk -F'\n' -vRS='\0' '
    {
      print NF
      for ( i = 1 ; i < NF ; i++ ) {
        j = split ( $i , a , " " )
        print "nb of fields = "j
        }
  }' infile

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient and concise way to do this given your input is always a file and not a stream is to just call `wc` outside of the script and use it's output inside it:

```
awk -v nr="$(wc -l < file)" '{print nr, NR, $0}' file
```

e.g.:

```
$ seq 3 > file
$ awk -v nr="$(wc -l < file)" '{print nr, NR, $0}' file
3 1 1
3 2 2
3 3 3
```